# How do I set an attribute to a dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

First and foremost, hello. I'm a college student and not a very experienced coder, so forgive me if I end up saying something really dumb.

Either way, I have a school project in which I have to create a functional website using Node.js, where people are able to log in and buy stuff.

Most of the stuff already works, but I am having trouble with a very specific thing which I simply cannot get to work, yet is essential to the project itself.

I import data from a mySql database into the website using AJAX, that data contains products that people can buy. Then, those products are appended to the HTML page itself, and dynamically create two buttons for each product that is appended, one which says "Buy Now" and the other which says "Learn More".

Now, those buttons are supposed to be somehow associated to the values of the database, but I have no idea how to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/getPacotes',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var pacoteSet1 = "<div class='col-md-4 pacotes'>";
                var pacoteSet2 = "<input id=btnPac"+
                      i + " type='button' name='comprar' value='Comprar Pacote'>";
                var pacoteSet3 = "</div>";
                var idPacote = data[i].idPacote;
                var nomePacote = data[i].Nome_Pacote;             
                $("#pacotes").append(pacoteSet1 +
                     "<h1>" + nomePacote + "</h1>" +
                     "<h1>" + nomePacote + "</h1>" +
                    "<h3>" + precoPacote + "euros/mes </h3>" +
                    pacoteSet2 + 
                    pacoteSet3);

            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

My teacher told me to give an attr to the buttons I create, and that's what I was pretty much trying to do now, but I dont know how to do that, I mean, if the buttons were static it would be pretty easy, but since the buttons are not there when the document is created, I dont know if this will work

```
$("#btnPac" + i).attr({"id": idPacote,
         "nome": nomePacote,
         "preco": precoPacote,

});
```

Anyway, Hopefully, I didn't sound too dumb and thanks in advance

TL:DR how do I give an attribute to a dynamically created button

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your jquery function like below:

```
$(document).find("#btnPac" + i).attr({"id": idPacote,
         "nome": nomePacote,
         "preco": precoPacote
});
```

This should be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that while creating the html for button element. By using string concatenation, which you are already using while setting the ID:

```
 var pacoteSet2 = "<input id=btnPac"+ i + "  nome='" + nomePacote + "' preco='" + precoPacote + "' type='button' name='comprar' value='Comprar Pacote'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloading the HTML with attributes is a bad idea in my opinion. You could create the Elements in JS, bind the data to it, and then append the button to the dom. Thats quite easy with jquery:

```
var button=$("<button>Show More</button>");//create
button.on("click",showMore.bind({name:"test"}));//add listener
$(document.body).append(button);//append

function showMore(){
   alert(this.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new input tag and set these attributes then append to your div with this code:

```
 $('<input/>', {
    id: 'btnPac' + i,
    nome: nomePacote ,
    preco: precoPacote ,
    type: 'button'
  }).appendTo("#pacotes");
```

You can do the same for your others (h1, h3)